# Deletion of millions of records without parallel hint and bulk collect

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have a table PROD_MAIN which have 750 million records on a single database. The database infrastructure is very basic and does not have any RACs on it. It is just 1 database. 
The requirement is to delete the records which are more than 1 year old. I wrote a PL SQL code with parallel hint and bulk collect. It takes very long time to execute. Please find the code below.

```
ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DML;

DECLARE
TYPE TABLE_DELETE IS TABLE OF ROWID;
T_DELETE TABLE_DELETE;
CURSOR C_DELETE IS
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(10) */ ROWID FROM PROD_MAIN WHERE RECORD_DATE < (TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 366);
L_DELETE_BUFFER PLS_INTEGER := 50000;
BEGIN
OPEN C_DELETE;
LOOP
FETCH C_DELETE BULK COLLECT
INTO T_DELETE LIMIT L_DELETE_BUFFER;
FORALL I IN 1..T_DELETE.COUNT
DELETE /*+ PARALLEL(10) */ PROD_MAIN WHERE ROWID = T_DELETE(I);
EXIT WHEN C_DELETE%NOTFOUND;
COMMIT;
END LOOP;
CLOSE C_DELETE;
COMMIT;
END;

ALTER SESSION DISABLE PARALLEL DML;
```

I also did NOLOGGING on the table. I created indexes and did stat gathering but the performance did not improve. So, is there any other way where I can delete the millions of records within 3 - 5 hours?

Comment: What fraction of the rows are you deleting?

Comment: @Justin Cave : I am deleting the rows which are more than 1 year old. When checked, the total records which needs to be deleted are 400 million out of 750 million.

Comment: OK.  And you have a couple hours of downtime?  Are there any triggers on the table?  Is this a parent or a child table in a foreign key constraint?

Comment: There are no triggers on this table. However I resolved it by creating a new duplicate table with the values that are greater than 366 days and truncated the main table. And renamed the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by creating a temporary table PROD_MAIN_TEMP which has the exact table structure like PROD_MAIN. After creating, I inserted the data which I want to keep. 
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(10) */ * FROM PROD_MAIN WHERE RECORD_DATE < (TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 366);
Dropped the table main table PROD_MAIN and renamed the temporary table PROD_MAIN_TEMP to PROD_MAIN.
This whole process completed in 3 hours.

Comment: "Diego Sal Diaz" suggested this solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the table is partitioned by date, you can truncate the partitions with more than one year (truncate a partition takes no time a dont degrades the table)

if it has no partitions, i think the best think you can do is not to try to remove all records in one single transaction. Try to remove a few records and put it in a loop. For example, i you want to delete 10.000 records you can do:

```
DELETE FROM your_table WHERE your_conditions LIMIT 10.000 (MySQL)
DELETE FROM your_table WHERE your_conditions AND rownum <10000 (Oracle)
```

Remember to optimize the table after finishing (or even alternated between deletes) due to it will degrade the index.

Depending on your environment requirements, another thing you can try is to create an empty table copy, and perform an INSERT from SELECT, inserting in the new table all the rows that you want to maintain. after that, truncate the original table, drop it, and rename the new one.

```
MyOriginalTable whit All Data
Create en Empty Copy: MyTemporalTable (without indexes)
Move valid data from MyOriginalTable to MyTemporalTable
Truncate and Drop MyOriginalTable
Create indexes in MyTemporalTable
Rename MyTemporalTable to MyORiginalTable
```

Comment: How do I partition the existing table PROD_MAIN with date? This is a new concept for me. Will the Database Administration does it or will the PL SQL developers do that ? And I am using Oracle DB. Also, I would need to delete atleast 400 million records in 2 to 3 hours

Comment: I think the partition should bebdone by the dba, but create the partition with such amoun of data will take a loot of time. If you can do the second option maybe could bebthe best. Just remember create the table copy eithout indexes and create them when the table is populated.

Comment: +1 for option 2 , create a new table, it is the most efficient way. https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2345591157689

Comment: Partitioning is an extra cost option on top of the enterprise edition license.  If someone describes their database infrastructure as "very basic", it seems unlikely that they would have the enterprise edition and the extra cost partitioning option.  Deleting in batches is almost certainly going to be slower than running a single `delete` statement that deletes all the data.  If the goal is to delete 400 million of 750 million rows and you have a downtime window then creating a new table and moving the data you want to keep over is reasonable.

Comment: @Justin Cave you are right, but in other rdbms like mysql it has no cost, and i tried to help any with a similar problem, even if they are no using oracle systems

Comment: Still curious about Partitioning. Will it help me to complete the delete within the scheduled downtime of 2 to 4 hours? 
Any ideas to the DBA on how to perform partition ?

Comment: @Cool_Oracle If you can have 2-4 hours of downtime, I really think that create a new table is the best way to face this issue. Partitioning is specially recommended for tables greater than 2Gb, but there are several types and strategies and the best one should suit the day by day requirements, and not a 1 single operation. However here you have two interesting links [Add Partitions to a existing table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_admin002.htm#i1007318) and [Truncate Partitions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_admin002.htm#i1008226)

Comment: Partitioning would only help *after* the table is partitioned.  And there's no way to partition an existing table.  So if the table is not already partitioned, then partitioning won't help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is: this table is master table for other table(s).

To speed up disable those foreign keys in other tables. Then delete rows then enable the indexes.

But the third solution of 'Diego Sal Diaz' to copy remaining row to temp table and rename it is good also.